# MSI Radeon 480 drivers on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon

Uh oh!  It appears I've screwed up the display settings for my current installation.  I just bought this new graphics card for a monitor I'll be getting soon, but in trying to get the resolution corrected in my Ubuntu installation, I've done something wrong and am no longer able to get into the desktop environment.  The command I used were an amalgamation of the following AskUbuntu links: [This most recent one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/465778/gnome-ubuntu-14-04-aticonfig-no-supported-adapters-detected-ati-radeon-6770m) as well as, previously, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690238/ubuntu-15-04-ati-radeon-graphics-issue).

So my rig is a desktop with an Intel cpu and a new [MSI Radeon](https://us.msi.com/Graphics-card/Radeon-RX-480-GAMING-X-8G.html#hero-overview) on a Samsung Evo with Ubuntu 15.04 recently installed.  After installing the card I logged over to my Ubuntu installation to find that the resolution was completely off.  I used those mentioned links to try and solve the problem but am now unable to continue using Ubuntu with a graphical interface and have to do everything on the command line.

Pending a solution to the current video card, what is a good way to get back to the previously working state that I was in?

Comment: The new AMD RX cards don't use the radeon driver and so fglrx won't work. Uninstall any graphics drivers you've already installed and reboot. Ubuntu should auto-detect and use amdgpu open source driver, you can check using `lspci -nnnk`. The kernel module in use for your card should show as amdgpu. Personally I couldn't get full resolution on the open source driver so I installed AMDGPU-PRO. Download and follow instructions from the AMD website [AMDGPU-PRO Driver for Linux](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx)

Comment: Awesome!  I actually don't have much experience with graphics drivers on Linux.  What is a command to check and/or purge the current drivers as you said?

Comment: I haven't used fglrx but a quick google shows `sudo apt purge fglrx*` or `sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*` or `sudo aticonfig --uninstall`. Note you may need to Ctrl-Alt-F2 and login to a text terminal and one of the above commands if it doesn't seem to work fully through the GUI terminal.

Comment: Ok, I'm now able to log back into the Gnome environment, and am working on getting AMDGPU-PRO installed, however I am running into issues with the version.  It appears that this is targeted to Ubuntu versions 12.04, 14.04, and 16.04, or the LTS, but not 15.04.  I also don't actually see the 14.04 install anywhere on the site or in the APT.

Comment: Just download the file that is on the website, version 16.30 and follow the install instructions. I understand it works on ubuntu 14.04 and up

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the case.  The install script for the program will not complete due to held packages.  I am unable to install amdgpu-pro due to held broken packages, although when i do `apt mark held` I get no output.  The package depends on `libvdpau-amdgpu-pro` but I can't get that one :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47552/discussion-between-grannysez-and-csteele5).

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --fix-missing` or `sudo apt-get --fix-missing`. After that you may also need to do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. If that doesn't work are you able to do a fresh install of ubuntu and install amdgpu-pro from there?

Comment: I just remembered there is a problem using AMDGPU-PRO with Gnome desktop ... see here for a fix [https://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794529/amdgpu-pro-install-on-ubuntu-gnome-16-04-with-r9-285-and-rx-480)